# PHP/HTML Communication for Raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, python, html

I am very novice in this field of programing so any guidance would be appreciated. I have a camera stream for my Rasp Pi and I just attached a servo to turn it around. I have broken down my problem into three stages.

1) HTML GUI for a simple two button, with a value box for camera degrees.

2) PHP scrip to read the value each time a button is pressed in html and write it down to a text file.

3) Python script that reads the text file and moves the camera accordingly.

I have completed step 3 which is to turn the servo around. I also made a small GUI as step 1 in html. My major concern is to link a client side html page to a php server side. My expertise end right here. I have a website hosted on my Pi so all I want is to be able to control the cameras position through a simple web page. Is there a simple way for html to talk to php? I can write a simple php code to write value to a text file if I can initially get data from the html button.

And to be exact, the button wont be passing an actual number, just an increment/decrement signal to the php where a hardcoded value with increase or decrease(Camera angle in degrees).

Here is my code so far.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Camera Control</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Camera Control</h1>

<p style="text-align: center;">
    <input name="Leftbutton" type="button" value="Left" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input maxlength="5" name="textbox" size="5" type="text" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="Rightbutton" type="button" value="Right" />
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Preview of the HTML]

---

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = " **Some value from the button, text or number** \n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

My goal is to avoid JavaScript or languages that I don't know, if there is a simple easy way I can get this done would be amazing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search for `php form handling` as nothing is being posted.

Comment: Seems like the right idea for me to go about, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This code below should be index.php:

```
<?php
  if($_GET['return'] == 'failed'){
    echo '<p>unable to execute command.<p>';
  }
?>

<style>
  #camera > input{
    margin-left 10px;
  }
</style>
<form id="camera" action="camera.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="left" value="left">
  <input maxlength="5" name="textbox" size="5" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" name="right" value="right">
</form>
```

Then for the PHP something like this:

```
<?php
  #camera.php

  if(isset($t = $_POST['textbox']) && isset($l = $_POST['left']) || isset($r = $_POST['right'])){
    if(isset($l){
      $v = "left";
    } elseif(isset($r)) {
      $v = "right";
    } else {
      header('Location: ./index.php?return="failed"');
      die();
    }

    if(!file_put_contents('data.txt', time() . "| $v:$t" . PHP_EOL)){
      header('Location: ./index.php?return="failed"');
      die();
    }

    header('Location: ./index.php');

    // if access to shell
    exec('python ./location/to/yourscript.py');
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test Page
  </title>
 </head>


 <body>
<form method="post" action="temp.php">
<input type="submit" value="Left" name="leftb">
<input type="submit" value="Right" name="rightb">
</form>  



 </body>
 </html>




<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

if ($_POST['leftb'])
{ echo "Left is pressed";
    $txt = -1;}


else if ($_POST['rightb'])
{ echo "Right is pressed";
    $txt = 1;}


fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);



sleep(1);

$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = 0;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);

fclose($myfile);

?>
```